# flutter assets_audio_player MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method open on channel assets_audio_player)

Tags: flutter, flutter-audioplayers

**assets_audio_player** show when lunch the app from **background notification**
MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method open on channel assets_audio_player)

in the foreground, it works fine but if the app launched from a background notification MissingPluginException error shows